# Script to Send Automated Emails via Outlook

Tags: python, macos, smtp, office365

I am attempting to set up a script that will fire off a series of emails automatically.
Below I have the code I am using to test this process.

```
import smtplib, ssl

username = 'me@company.com' # input('Enter username: ')
password = 'mypassword' # input('Enter password: ')

port = 443

smtp_server = "outlook.office365.com"
sender_email = username
receiver_email = "me@company.com"
message = "Hi there! This message is sent from Python."


context = ssl.create_default_context()

# s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
# s.set_debuglevel(1)

with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gx8k/repos/namespace_auditer/./send_mail.py", line 15, in <module>
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('outlook.office365.com')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 1056, in _get_socket
    new_socket = super()._get_socket(host, port, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

I want to send the email from Outlook specifically.
Checking the 'Accounts' settings I see my server is running on port 443 and has a domain of https://outlook.office365.com/subdomain/Exchange.asmx

I'm only using the outlook.office365.com portion of it since that's all that is shown in most examples I see. However I have tried using the full domain as well as just https://outlook.office365.com/. Nothing seems to work.

I have been using the info found [here](https://realpython.com/python-send-email/) to guide me.

Originally I was using the domain smtp.office365.com but changed it after finding outlook.office365.com in my accounts settings. It fails with the same error anyway.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gx8k/repos/namespace_auditer/./send_mail.py", line 15, in <module>
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.office365.com')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 1050, in __init__
    SMTP.__init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 341, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 1056, in _get_socket
    new_socket = super()._get_socket(host, port, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

I also tried with port 587 rather than 443. (443 is what I find in my outlook settings) - same error either way.

Update: I think the answer to my question is that mac's don't use SMTP...now I have to figure out how to do this in IMAP.

```
What protocol does Outlook for Mac use?
By default, Outlook is set to IMAP protocol. If you choose to set your account on IMAP, you may use the following settings then click Add Account.
```

Additional Update:

I ended up scratching this approach altogether. I ended up using an internal API service to send notifications out to all relevant parties.

Answer (score 0):

For Office 365 accounts, the SMTP server name is smtp.office365.com, post 587, TLS on.

Comment: I should have mentioned, that's what I used at first. Then made the adjustment to outlook.office365.com when I checked my accounts settings. Just changed it back so I can grab the error associated with that. It takes a while to fail.

Comment: OK, it failed... and it's basically the same error anyway. I'll add it to the original post

Comment: Port must be 587

Comment: Another thing I need to add...I used port 587 as well when testing the smtp domain.

Comment: Check the SMTP settings from an email client (Outlook?)  that you know works.